# Im getting error when excecuting `flutter doctor` in cmd or powershell

Tags: flutter

Im switching android to cross-platform flutter and follow some tutorials in youtube. I've download the latest sdk of flutter and when running the `flutter doctor` it get me some errors like this see pictures below.

[image]

I tried turning off my firewall and anti virus but still the same
I already install from android studio the flutter plugins and run again the `doctor`

Answer (score 1):

**Devices:**

You would need to manually run your simulator for flutter doctor to remove the warning for that

**Plugin:**

If you're using Studio, once you've installed the Flutter and Dart plugin you would need to restart the IDE so that the plugins would load

Answer (score 1):

I can see two issues in your case, 
1) Android licenses not accepted.
2) Flutter and Dart plugin not installed in your IDE. If you use Android Studio and IntelliJ then you have to install both plugins in both IDEs.

So, to solve the first issue you have to accept all the required licenses by SDK. So, write the following command to get rid of it.

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

After adding above command you have to accept all the list of licenses one by one to get ahead. To accept each license press **y** every time until you accept all the licenses.

Now, to solve your second issue you have to install dart and flutter plugins in your both IDEs Android Studio and Intellij IDEA.

In your case, you have not installed dart and flutter plugin. So, close your project and go to **"Welcome Screen"** of IDE where you will see a **"Configure"** button. click on it and select **"Plugins"**.

Now, search for **Flutter** and **Dart** and install both of them in your IDEs which you use for flutter development. After installing both restart your IDE to apply new changes.

Now, you're Done with the setup. Now, you can run your project in real device or emulator by configuring them.

Comment: you have to accept all the licenses. add the license command again and accept all the remaining ones by pressing y every time.